# Cron not working

Tags: 7, cron

I have a `hook_cron` that regularly import contents from external site via `drupal_http_request`. However, I noticed that cron is not running. I am using Elysia cron module and I defined the job to run every 5 minutes `*/5 * * * *`.

Out of curiosity I put this code `variable_set('maintenance_mode', 1)` to check if the site will go offline after five minutes but it wont.

I even add an entry `*/1 * * * * import_cron` to the `Script` textarea on Elysia config page. But still not working. Any advice?